# Derivation of $\cos\theta = \frac{u{\cdot}v}{||u||||v||}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I saw the above equation in my Linear Algebra textbook, tried to derive it myself and failed.

I basically tried using cosine rule, but was unable to get the equation. I drew some diagrams (on paper, not on PC (I can't draw on PC)) and my hand drawing is also ugly, so I can't really post my attempt at deriving the equation. I'm not really good at cramming equations (save a few), and try to derive the equations myself, or at least learn the derivations so I can arrive at them myself if I need it.

Comment: "above derivation" which?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Hint: the law of cosine.

Comment: In euclidean space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\cos\theta = \frac{|u|^2+|v|^2-|u-v|^2}{2|u||v|} = \frac{\sum u_i ^2 + \sum v_i^2 - \sum(u_i-v_i)^2}{2|u||v|} = \frac{\sum u_i ^2 + \sum v_i^2 - (\sum u_i^2 + \sum v_i^2 - \sum 2u_i v_i)}{2|u||v|} = \frac{u.v}{|u||v|}
$$

Comment: this solution is for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

$$
u.v = u_xv_x+u_yv_y = |u|\cos(\alpha_u)|v|\cos(\alpha_v)+|u|\sin(\alpha_u)|v|\sin(\alpha_v)
$$
$$
u.v = |u||v|\left(\cos(\alpha_u)\cos(\alpha_v)-\sin(\alpha_u)\sin(\alpha_v)\right)
$$
$$
u.v = |u||v|\left(\cos(\alpha_u - \alpha_v)\right) = |u||v|\cos(\theta)
$$
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{u.v}{|u||v|}
$$

Comment: this solution is for $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: My question is for $\mathbb{R}^n$.